# How can I hide some navigation links in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I copied this menu from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp). I've edited some things (float three links to the right and I've changed some colours).

Desktop view:
[image: Here you see the desktop view]

Mobile view:
[image: And here you can see the mobile view]

But so as you can see the projects link show up in the mobile view, that's not what I wanted to. How can I disable that projects link? I've already tried some things like: :not(:first-child) in CSS.

Here is my code:

```js
function jsnav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("js-nav");
  if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  nav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .float-right {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav.responsive {position: relative;}
  nav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  nav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

main {
  padding: 40px 40px 20px 80px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
  main {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>CSS Nav HTML &amp; CSS JS</title>
</head>
<body>


  <nav id="js-nav">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <div class="float-right">
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="jsnav()">
      &#9776;
    </a>
  </nav>

<main>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</main>

<script src="js/navigation.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to hide that project links ? so all the links from `float-right` should be hidden ?

Comment: Yes that's right, only when the hamburger button is touched the float-right links should be visible

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into all the details about why using `float` is a bad practice for layout. You should look into other solutions like the famous and very largerly used `flexbox`

You can read about it here:[MDN flexbox basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or on other sites.

So, back to your problem. A solution would be to hide them all `.float-right a { display: none }` and then show them again when you need them. As i understand, `nav` will have class `responsive` so, add show the links when the nav has that class `nav.responsive .float-right a { display: none }`

```js
function jsnav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("js-nav");
  if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .float-right a{
    display: none;
  }
  nav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .float-right {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  nav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  nav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  nav.responsive .float-right a{
    display: block;
  }
}

main {
  padding: 40px 40px 20px 80px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="js-nav">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="float-right">
    <a href="#">Projects</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="jsnav()">
      &#9776;
    </a>
</nav>

<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</main>
```